# Version control recommendation with php/eclipse?

Tags: php, eclipse, version-control

Currently I do all updates manually, meaning when I make changes to the code I manually ftp the files that were changed to the server. Obviously Im playing with fire, so want to start using a more structured process of releasing updates for my php projects. Im using Windows 7 with Eclipse as my IDE. I have a linux dev box, what version control program would you recommend that I can interact with Eclipse to check out a copy from my dev box? Make changes and commit those changes back to dev, test the code and be able to commit the changes to a production box? (Im assuming that is the correct process?)

Comment: I would never start with a centralized vcs anymore. Its like feeding dinosaurs ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subversion or Git are good choices. They both have plugins that integrate into eclipse and will do what you need.

They do use somewhat different paradigms so choose the one that you are most comfortable with.

Comment: @datasage Thanks for the info! To clarify is the process I mention the correct way this would work? Check out from dev via eclipse, make changes. Commit changes to dev. Test it and if all works commit from dev to production? Or would I commit from eclipse to prod?

Comment: Not exactly. Your repository exits independently of your environments. With one person you can keep a fairly simple workflow. You work in your development/testing environment until you have completed version, then you update production to that version. If you want to, you could create a tag each time you have a production version completed. Then all you do is check out that tag to your production environment.

Comment: @Datasage Ok so I create a repository on my workstation, import my project files and now I can check it out via eclipse to work on it. My confusion is once Im done with the changes what would be the next step to be able to test my changes locally on my dev box? Do I have to install svn on my dev box and be able to push my new changes to the dev box so I can test?

Comment: Yes, you checkout your repository on your dev box and then update to the latest version to test.

Comment: @datasage Ok think I got it. Create repository on my workstation. Then on my dev server I can check it out in my www root, test it on dev and if everything works then I can hop on my prod server and check out the latest version in the www folder. Is that a basic understanding of how its done?

Comment: That's the basics of it. There are other features you could use, but are not really needed if you are only working with a team of 1.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the info! This page also is helping me understand best "patterns" http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.commonpatterns.html

Answer (score 1):

I would use a DVCS like git or mercurial with a branching. I use a slight variation of the branching model described here:

http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Let me describe to you my deployment workflow:

I have 4 environments:

1. `prod`: Production - i.e: LIVE
2. `stage`: Staging server a.k.a: test environment. This is the final stop before code gets promoted to prod.
3. `int`: Integration server
4. `dev`: Development

Each developer gets his own local copy of the code and works with the branching model described previously.

Integration environment continuously merges the stuff devs push out (I use a simple commit-hook with a shell script that does this. You can also consider more sophisticated CI tools that could do this). Int will have the latest 'bleeding edge'/'latest and greatest' version of the application. Unit testing is used to make sure no one breaks anything badly.

Just before a release, the codebase is moved to stage. Stuff like functional tests and UA testing is done at this point.  If everything looks OK, then I push from stage to prod and the code is then live.

I personally use NetBeans as my IDE - there are plugins that nicely integrates to git/mercurial.

Lastly: a development workflow/deployment strategy is something that is unique to your project/organization. I just (**broadly**) described mine - all points may or may not apply to you but I hope you now have an idea of how things should ideally work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer as well. I will keep this as a favorite to come back to if I need to grow.